# Why my SSDs are in /dev/hdx instead of /dev/sdx on CentOS 5.9?

Tags: linux, centos, hard-disk, sata

I have two SSDs Kingston SH103S3240G plugged on SATA ports of my Intel Server Board S3000AH.
The SSDs apear like a PATA device (hdx instead of sdx) on my CentOS 5.9.

[I'm having problems related to high iowait](https://serverfault.com/questions/521322/centos-5-extremely-slow-when-is-running-a-download). Does this have something related?

On motherboard setup the `SATA mode` are `Enhanced`.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dmesg` just after reboot to pastebin.com or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Devices should only show up as `/dev/hd*` when your kernel is using the ancient IDE subsystem instead of the modern `libata` interface to talk with your hard disk controller. With `libata`, even old IDE devices should show up as `/dev/sd*` because libata exposes all devices through the SCSI subsystem.

> I'm having problems related to high iowait. Does this have something related?

When you're using the IDE subsystem, you're probably forcing your SATA controller into IDE emulation which could have a negative impact on the performance, yes.

> On motherboard setup the SATA mode are Enhanced.

Hmm... does your BIOS have an AHCI option? Enabling AHCI would be the best option because AHCI is the most modern and the fastest interface, but the mainboard seems to be rather old... it is possible that it doesn't support AHCI. Upgrading to a newer mainboard could solve your issues.

Please provice the output of the following commands, so we can figure out why your server is using the ancient IDE subsystem:

- `uname -a`
- `lspci -nn`
- `dmesg`
- `lsmod`